# Where "this" is referring

Tags: java

Mate, I have a very simple code where I am printing "this" along with "object" of the class. As per theory "this" refers to current "object", but in my code it looks like "this" is not referring to current object. Need some guidance please

This is my output :

```
costructor this hash : Sandbox.Apple@1540e19d
newApple hash : Sandbox.Apple@1540e19d
this hash : Sandbox.Apple@1540e19d
costructor this hash : Sandbox.Apple@677327b6
apples hash : Sandbox.Apple@677327b6
this hash : Sandbox.Apple@1540e19d
```

My Question is why the last line of the output i.e.

```
this hash : Sandbox.Apple@1540e19d
```

is referring to `1540e19d`instead of `677327b6`

```
public class ThisKeyword {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    Apple newApple = new Apple("Green Apple");
    System.out.println("newApple hash : " + newApple);

    newApple.calculateQuantity();
    newApple.testThis();
}

}

class Apple {
    String name;

public Apple(String name) {
    this.name = name;
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    System.out.println("costructor this hash : " + this);
}

public void calculateQuantity() {

    System.out.println("this hash : " + this);
}

public void testThis() {
    Apple apples = new Apple("Red Apple");
    System.out.println("apples hash : " + apples);
    System.out.println("this hash : " + this);
}

}
```

Comment: You create a new instance of `Apple` and assigned it to `apples`, it has no relationship to the current instance of `Apple` (referenced by `this`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because when you call method `newApple.testThis();`, the context of this is the object `newApple` which has a reference address `1540e19d`. So statement `System.out.println("this hash : " + this);` should print the address  `1540e19d`.

Meanwhile, statements:

```
Apple apples = new Apple("Red Apple");
System.out.println("apples hash : " + apples);
```

gave the new address of the new object `apples` ,which is `677327b6`.

Comment: Silly me ... got it ... Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It's working as it should.

You're creating two Apple objects here, newApple (created in the main method) and apples (created in testThis()).

In Apple.testThis(), the line `System.out.println("this hash : " + this);` is referencing the Apple object you're calling it from which is the variable `newApple`, not `apples`.

Answer (score 0):

`this` refer to current instance of the defined class, mean it refers to the object whose method is being called.

The last line output is the product of `newApple.testThis()` and of course it refers to newApple with `1540e19d`

Answer (score 0):

The last method call you make is `newApple.testThis();` in which you call `System.out.println("this hash : " + this);`, since you are calling the method on `newApple`, then `this` refers to `newApple`, not `apples`.